# sorting database with more than 1 keys in excel vba

Tags: database, excel, vba, sorting

i want to sort a database with 4 keys but whenever am adding the 4th key its saying named argument not found whereas it sorting the database with these 3 keys.. how to add 4th one in this..??

```
Range("A1:E" & lastrow).Sort key1:=Range("A1:A" & lastrow), order1:=xlAscending, _
                             key2:=Range("C1:C" & lastrow), order2:=xlAscending, _
                             key3:=Range("D1:D" & lastrow), order3:=xlDescending, _
                             Header:=xlYes
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Range.Sort method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx) has a maximum of three keys per process. However, if you sort by the extra keys first, then resort by the three most primary keys, you achieve the same results.

```
With Range("A1:E" & lastrow)
    'sort on the 4th key first (column E)
    .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(5), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
    'sort on the 1st, 2nd and 3rd keys (columns A, C and D)
    .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                Key2:=.Columns(3), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                Key3:=.Columns(4), Order3:=xlAscending, _
                Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
End With
```

This produces the same result as if there was a `Key4:=.Columns(5), Order4:=xlAscending` allowed in the method.

I try to use a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) to ensure an easy method of defining the parent of the keys. Your original code relied upon the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which is not always reliable.